# bootstrap a dataset in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, statistics-bootstrap

I need to perform bootstrapping for a dataset in R. The data is in the form of a list which contains two matrices and has following properties:

- Both the matrices are n by m and contain only positive integers (including 0).

  ```
  data <- list(a=matrix(,n,m), b=matrix(,n,m))
  ```
- A number of marbles, say 10000 are distributed into each matrix, i.e., 10000 is divided in n*m parts. In other words, sum of all entries for each matrix is fixed.

  ```
  > sum(data$a)
  [1] 10000
  > sum(data$b)
  [1] 10000
  ```
- The marbles are distributed according to affinity of *ij*-th elements for marbles, i.e. how many marbles end up as *ij*-th entry of the matrix depends on a probability associated with every cell of the matrix.
- The probabilities associated with elements are different for the two matrices.

My goal is to estimate the parameters which lead to underlying probabilities. My model assumes `2n` parameters, `n` for the number of rows and one set for each matrix. The parameters combine in complex manner and so the two matrices must be analyzed together.

```
    parameters <- data.frame(a=numeric(n), b=numeric(n))
```

Right now, this is the approach I am using:

1. I define a function `SGen` which takes for input a matrix containing probabilities associated with all sites, generates a dataset using these probabilities and returns it.

   ```
   SGen <- function(freq) {
      #generate sample
      ...
   }
   ```
2. For non-parametric bootstrap (which is what I want to implement for now), I run an experiment, and calculate the observed probability associated with each *ij* element by dividing the observed matrices with 10000. Let us call it `freq` for now. So, `freq` is a list with two matrices.

   ```
   freq <- list(a=data$a/10000, b=data$b/10000)
   ```
3. Next, I replicate 100 samples for data by passing `freq` to `SGen`.
4. I pass all the replicates to another pre-defined function, `analyze` which gives me 100 n by 2 matrices containing the parameters.
5. Next I calculate the mean and sd of the entries between all the matrices to get an n by 2 matrix containing means and another containing sd. So, the desired value for say (1,5)th element of mean matrix is the mean of (1,5)th elements of all 100 replicates.

While the approach works, I would like to use boot package in R for the job. I want to do that because then I can use all the functions in boot package for later analyses and I also like the way essential information is stored in format of boot class. Another important reason I would like to use boot package is that it offers an easy way to make use of multicore capabilities of my computer. So, can you please guide me on how to use `boot` for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap` with almost any function in the following way (taken from `?bootstrap`):

```
# To bootstrap functions of more complex data structures, 
# write theta so that its argument x
# is the set of observation numbers  
# and simply  pass as data to bootstrap the vector 1,2,..n. 
# For example, to bootstrap
# the correlation coefficient from a set of 15 data pairs:
xdata <- matrix(rnorm(30),ncol=2)
n <- 15
theta <- function(x,xdata){ cor(xdata[x,1],xdata[x,2]) }
results <- bootstrap(1:n,20,theta,xdata)
```

`theta` is the function to bootstrap.

The only problem with this approach (I believe) is that theta can only return a vector (not a dataframe/matrix of multiple values in one go). So, if your `theta` function returns anything else than a vector it might not work.

## Update for the `boot` package:

The approach would be similar using the `boot` function from the `boot` package. It takes `data`, the data as a vector, matrix, or dataframe, and `statistic`, "a function which when applied to data returns a vector containing the statistic(s) of interest." For non-parametric bootstrap, the `statistic` function must take (at least) two arguments: the original data, and a vector of indices, frequencies or weights.

So, the key is to write one function that implements steps 1-5 on the subset of the data given by the index, e.g:

```
theta <- function(data, indices) {
    ## exact subsetting operation depends on the format of data
    subset_data = data[indices,]
    ## perform the calculations in steps 1-5 here on subset_data
}
```

Then you should be able to call `theta` like this:

```
boot(data, theta)
```

Comment: `bootstrap` function was developed for a specific project. `boot` package which the authors of `bootstrap` recommend is what I am trying to use. `bootstrap` does not have parallel processing features. [link]https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/bootstrap.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Major problem in what I am trying to do is in controlling the way `boot` function generates new samples. From my reading, I think the only way to control how new samples are drawn is by making it a parametric bootstrap. But my dataset has grown more complex and I am looking into the `foreach` package now for a more direct implementation of what I want to do.